# How to assign the response of an ajax request to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I created an AJAX function that takes two arguments, sends them to a script in PHP and formats them as I wish, like this :

```
function createUniqueKey (arg1, arg2) {
  $.post("/ajax/documents.php", {arg_1: arg1, arg_2 : arg2}, function(data){
    console.log(data) //Good result
    return data
  }, "text");
}
```

When the user clicks a button, it starts the ajax request, the problem is that I can not assign it to a variable, I tested that but without success

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
  ...
  var uniqueKey = createUniqueKey(arg1, arg2)
  console.log(uniqueKey) //undefined
  ...
});
```

The `console.log` present in the function gives me a result but the `console.log` of the variable returns me `undefined`

How to sign the result to the variable (`uniqueKey`)?

Answer (score 0):

Because this is asynchronous, you have a few options. The basic one is to use a callback:

```
function createUniqueKey (arg1, arg2, callback) {
  $.post("/ajax/documents.php", {arg_1: arg1, arg_2 : arg2}, function(data){
    console.log(data) //Good result
    callback(data);
  }, "text");
}

$('#btn').click(function() {
  createUniqueKey(arg1, arg2, function(uniqueKey){
      console.log(uniqueKey);
  })      
});
```

Another option is to figure out how to implement it as a Promise or using Async functions:

```
function createUniqueKey (arg1, arg2) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.post("/ajax/documents.php", {arg_1: arg1, arg_2 : arg2}, function(data){
            console.log(data) //Good result
            resolve(data);
          }, "text");
    })

}

$('#btn').click(function() {
  createUniqueKey(arg1, arg2).then(function(uniqueKey) {
    console.log(uniqueKey);
  })
});
```

The .click callback is equivalent to this

```
$('#btn').click(async function() {
  var uniqueKey = await createUniqueKey(arg1, arg2);
  console.log(uniqueKey);
});
```

Comment: Wow I did not think it was so complicated, but there is a lot of other things that happen when you click the button, I have to use ``asynchronous`` ?

Comment: It's not complicated when you figure out how Promises work and why they're needed. You'd benefit from looking up a Promise tutorial

Comment: Thank you but I do not understand where to put ``var = uniqueKey``

Comment: I tried to use your code but it does not work, when I use callback like this ``var uniqueKey =   createUniqueKey(arg1, arg2, function(uniqueKey){
      return uniqueKey;
  }) `` my variable is ``undefined``

Comment: Because that's not what you do. I didn't put that in my code for a reason: that is incorrect.You have access to the uniqueKey variable *inside the callback*. That's the only place you have access to it. You have to research how Asynchronous javascript works to understand what's going on here.